# jprofiler's triggers doesnt save snapshots

Tags: triggers, jprofiler

Jprofiler doesnt save snapshot if you use triggers. can some one help me?
Where can I find the location of saved jps file?
[image: jprofiler trigger]

Comment: Maybe the path is not writable by the profiled process? Add a "print message" trigger to check on stdout if the trigger is actually invoked.

Comment: is it ok, that I use jprofiler on my local machine and connecting to remote linux server?

Comment: Yes, but then the snapshot file will be saved on the remote machine and `c:\test.jps` will not be a writable path.

Comment: thanks, that make sense. I solved the problem.